# Signed SDK with Proguard Failure

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I'm trying to complile my app with minifyEnabled set to true, so that I can obfuscate the code. I get this error when doing so:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

The app compiles perfectly when minifyEnabled is set to false.

Here's the complete ProGuard log from the Gradle Console :

http://pastebin.com/hmGNcqUn // Was unable to paste the whole thing here because it was too large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've forgotten to add some proguard rules for the libraries you're using. I mainly saw warnings for [retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/), so just add the rules you're given at the documentation:

```
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
```

If there're warnings left, find the libraries responsible and add appropriate proguard rules for these.

Comment: That does it. Thanks a lot. I was using Proguard for the first time and had no idea.